# Incrementally add pandas column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  trade_id   tradedate   settledate    amt 
3136  6828     20200616    20200630   15000000.0     
3136  6934     20200616    20200630   15000000.0    
3136  7007     20200618    20200630   30000000.0     
3136  7050     20200620    20200630   25000000.0  
3137  7091     20200612    20200630   25000000.0  
3137  7092     20200615    20200630   25000000.0
```

There are two things that I want to perform.

Add the previous amount when the transaction happened on a specific date.Ex:for id 3136
2 Transactions happened on 16th June, next 18th and next on 20th.
So output will be:

```
id   tradedate  amt
3136 20200616   30000000
3136 20200618   60000000
3136 20200620   85000000
3137 20200612   25000000
3137 20200615   50000000
```

Next task would be find out missing dates and fill with last calculated amt.So final output will be like this:

```
  id   tradedate  amt
    3136 20200616   30000000
    3136 20200617   30000000
    3136 20200618   60000000
    3136 20200619   60000000
    3136 20200620   85000000
    3137 20200612   25000000
    3137 20200613   25000000
    3137 20200614   25000000
    3137 20200615   50000000
```

How can I achieve this in efficient way?
Tried with this:

```
 df_agg = df_joined.groupby(['id', 'tradedate'])[
            'amt'].agg('sum').reset_index()
        df_agg['cumsum'] = df_agg.groupby('id').amt.cumsum()
```

But not able to get the missing dates part here.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` to get sum by `id` and `tradedate` but first convert `tradedate` to a real date for upsampling:

```
df['tradedate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tradedate'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

```
>>> df.groupby(['id', 'tradedate'])['amt'].sum() \
      .groupby('id').cumsum().reset_index(level=0) \
      .resample('D').pad().reset_index()

   tradedate    id         amt
0 2020-06-12  3137  25000000.0
1 2020-06-13  3137  25000000.0
2 2020-06-14  3137  25000000.0
3 2020-06-15  3137  50000000.0
4 2020-06-16  3136  30000000.0
5 2020-06-17  3136  30000000.0
6 2020-06-18  3136  60000000.0
7 2020-06-19  3136  60000000.0
8 2020-06-20  3136  85000000.0
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if dates overlapped between id's. Change `df.loc[5, 'tradedate'] = '20200617'` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['id','tradedate'])['amt'].sum().groupby('id').cumsum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     id  tradedate         amt
0  3136   20200616  30000000.0
1  3136   20200618  60000000.0
2  3136   20200620  85000000.0
3  3137   20200612  25000000.0
4  3137   20200615  50000000.0
```

Then,

```
df_out['tradedate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_out['tradedate'], format='%Y%m%d')
df_out.groupby("id").apply(
    lambda x: x.set_index("tradedate")
               .reindex(pd.date_range(x["tradedate"].min(), x["tradedate"].max(), freq="D"))
               .reset_index()
               .ffill()
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       index      id         amt
0 2020-06-16  3136.0  30000000.0
1 2020-06-17  3136.0  30000000.0
2 2020-06-18  3136.0  60000000.0
3 2020-06-19  3136.0  60000000.0
4 2020-06-20  3136.0  85000000.0
5 2020-06-12  3137.0  25000000.0
6 2020-06-13  3137.0  25000000.0
7 2020-06-14  3137.0  25000000.0
8 2020-06-15  3137.0  50000000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin this cat but here's my solution>

```
df.tradedate  = pd.to_datetime(df.tradedate, format='%Y%m%d')
(df.
 groupby(['id', 'tradedate'])['amt'].
 sum().
 groupby('id').
 cumsum().
 reset_index().
 set_index('tradedate').
 groupby('id').
 apply(lambda x: x.drop('id',axis=1).asfreq('D', method= 'ffill')).
 reset_index()
 )
```